# What does "each one of you sort of drag around with you" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrases

I heard this quoted sentence from [the Yale's Death Course](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gh-6HyTRNNY#t=15m38s) at Youtube. How to understand "drag around with you" in boldface?

> I take it the idea of body is a familiar one. It's this lump of fresh and bone and muscle that's sitting here in front of you that each one of you sort of **drag around with you**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question.  But, first, instead of asking, "How to understand?" you should ask, "What does [X] mean?" or, "What is meant by the bold phrase?"

Second, the professor is describing the **corporeal** body in order to distinguish it from the metaphysical or spiritual self that he later describes.  Specifically, what you "*drag around with you*" is the your physical body: your bones, your muscles, your organs, skin, hair, and so on.